# New Content on Site Won't Appear Unless Refreshed or Browsing Data Deleted

Tags: php, html, css, web

I have a website where I post update messages regularly for other users to read.
New content won't appear unless I refresh the page or I clear my browsing data.
This isn't a huge problem for myself, but will be problematic for other users unless I tell them to refresh their pages every time they visit the site.

How can I fix this?
My site is consisted of html, css, php, sql, and a little javascript.

Comment: Do you have some cacheing options on, on your server ?

Comment: since you talk about deleting browser data then you can [blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: No, I do not have any chacheing options on. The problem is that if I've visited the site before and I go to the site, It shows me the old version of the site. Only once I refresh the page or clear browsing data will it be displayed and updated.So If a user has visited the site before, there is no way of knowing if any changes have been made, unless the user refreshes the page every time he/she visits the page. Is this a caching issue?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is caching issue.

add this `headers` before `session_start()`.

`header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
 header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
 header("Pragma: no-cache");`

Comment: The problem is that if I've visited the site before and I go to the site, It shows me the old version of the site. Only once I refresh the page or clear browsing data will it be displayed and updated. So If a user has visited the site before, there is no way of knowing if any changes have been made, unless the user refreshes the page every time he/she visits the page. Is this a caching issue?

Comment: Also, I don't have anywhere on my code where I "told the script to cache." Could this be the issue?

Comment: For some reason, it's not having issues anymore. It could be the browser or the servers being weird at that time. But if it happens again, I'll try your code and let you know if it works. Thanks for your help! :)